# Query Data from Firebase and write in UITextfield

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, firebase, uitextfield

I'm trying to pull data from my firebase project and write the field value in a UITextfield. I can't seem to figure out how to query the data needed for the UITextfields from the firebase field values correctly.

Is there anyway to do this? I have only seen videos of people adding firebase documents to a tableview, not any for direct pull of a firebase value to a UITextfield.

I've tried:

1. Switching the constants to instance the UITextfield Outlets and optionally unwrap as text fields `let username = data[USERNAME] as? UITextField ?? "anonymous"`
2. Creating variables of the UITextfields and equal the collections array data. So something kind like... `let self.username = Userdata[0]` but I keep getting "expected pattern error"

I know these may not be appropriate syntax but this is the first time I've ever coded and attempted to make an app, but I can't find any tutorial to follow for this scenario. So any information greatly appreciated, Thanks.

Heres what I've got so far...

```
import UIKit

import FirebaseDatabase 
import Firebase

class ProfileVC: UIViewController {





@IBOutlet weak var userImage: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var username: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var firstname: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var userEmail: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var lastname: UITextField!

@IBOutlet private weak var bgView: UIView!

//variables
private var Userdatas = [Userdata]()
private var usersCollectionRef: CollectionReference!



override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    
    usersCollectionRef = Firestore.firestore().collection(USERS_REF)
}



override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool){
usersCollectionRef.getDocuments { (snapshot, error) in
    if let err = error {
        debugPrint("Error fetching docs: \(err) ")
    } else {
        guard let snap = snapshot else{return}
        for document in snap.documents {
            let data = document.data()
            let username = data[USERNAME] as? String ?? "anonymous"
            let firstname = data[FIRST_NAME] as? String ?? "Anonymous"
            let lastname = data[LAST_NAME] as? String ?? "Anonymous"
            let email = data[EMAIL] as? String ?? "Anonymous"
            let documentID = document.documentID
            
            let newuserData = Userdata(username: username, email: email, firstname: firstname, lastname: lastname, documentID: documentID)
    
            
        }
     
    }
}

       }
```

Comment: are you getting data ? username firstname ?

Comment: Yep! So when I do -   'print(newuserData.username,email,firstname,lastname)' it prints out all the values within firebase but I'm just stuck as to finding a line of code to take one of these values, and insert it in the corresponding IBOutlets set at the top of the script?

Comment: so you can assign that to your textfields ?

Comment: Well sheeeet... Okay yeah it was just the fact that I had 'let' in front of self.username and what worked was just self.username.text = newuserData.username. Appreciate the help tho @jawadAli

Comment: so you got the answer ?